# Is it possible to print result during loop instantly without javascript?

Tags: php, loops, sleep, echo

Here is example of code I'm expecting to print message each second.

```
set_time_limit(0);

foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    echo $value;

    sleep(1);
}
```

I'm wondering is it possible to output results during each step in loop instantly, without waiting until it stops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes. 
you can do it using php's flush mechanism.

for example:

```
   <?
    ob_implicit_flush(true);
    foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    echo $value;

    sleep(1);
}
    ?>
```

Comment: Might work. But won't this just waste a lot of bandwidth for padding spaces?

Comment: i changed it more to reflect his above for loop.  if he wants to output and delay by a second, as long at the time limit doesnt get exceeded he is fine

Comment: @Dan: What padding spaces? How does this waste bandwidth? The client receives the same data, just at different times.

Answer (score 1):

That's not really possible since the webserver caches the result. The client may get new data as the output cache fills up and sends a new http packet, but it's not good practice to do it like that, because php scripts also timeout, so the results of such an approach can be ambiguous.

Edit: you can make php clear the cache using php's [ob_flush](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php) as in `ob_flush();`. However this still leaves the problem that the script might timeout, so you cannot keep doing this for a very long time.

A much better solution would be to make AJAX calls periodically or use WebSockets to keep a persistent connection to the server, in order to get new data as it comes out.

Edit 2: For WebSockets, it's not that short to post here. Also, it only works in HTTP5, Chrome 8 supports it and probably Firefox 4 and Safari 5 as well. Here is a tutorial of using Websockets with PHP: [WebSockets with PHP](http://www.flynsarmy.com/2010/05/php-web-socket-chat-application/)

Comment: can you provide an example with Web Sockets?

Comment: never implemented any solution with WebSockets myself, but there are tutorials and frameworks out there (also PHP plugin) that make it easy to use them. The idea is that they offer persistent connections so the server may just send a WebSocket packet back and the browser will immediately be notified.